# does the MailMessage require any setting to initialize?

Tags: c#, php

In my console program, I want to send email to someone by using `System.Net.Mail.MailMessage`. However, I cannot initialize it :(

namespace:

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Mail;
```

code:

```
class emailHelper
{
    string to = "jane@address.com";
    string from = "ben@address.com";
    MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);// errors here
}
```

the error message is about :

> A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or
> property 'programA.emailHelper.from'
>
> A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or
> property 'programA.emailHelper.to'

I have no idea that do I miss something to set before using MailMessage.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message give you all the information.

> A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or
>   property

So if you want to make it work, you should make your string fields static. Which I doubt is what you want.

```
class emailHelper
{
    static string to = "jane@address.com";
    static string from = "ben@address.com";
    MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);// errors here
}
```

Like I said this is not what you want from one helper method, to have static to and from address. Your code should look like this:

```
public class EmailHelper
{
    public string To {get; set;}
    public string From {get; set;}
    public MailMessage message {get; set;}

    public EmailHelper(string to, string from)
    {
         To = to;
         From = from;

         message = new MailMessage(from, to);
    }

}
```

In this case you have addresses which are coming out of the helper and you can create multiple `MailMessage` classes.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message stated

> A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or
>   property

Which means you cant use a field to initialize another field. But you can make use of the constructor here, your class implementation will be  like the following:

```
class emailHelper
{
    string to = "jane@address.com";
    string from = "ben@address.com";
    MailMessage message; // Declare here
    public emailHelper() // Constructor
    {
        message = new MailMessage(from, to);//initialize here
    }
}
```

Or use a read only property getter like this:

```
public MailMessage Message
{
    get { return new MailMessage(from, to); }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> A field initializer cannot reference the nonstatic field, method, or
>   property 'field' Instance fields cannot be used to initialize other
>   instance fields outside a method. If you are trying to initialize a
>   variable outside a method, consider performing the initialization
>   inside the class constructor

Check the Documentation : [Compiler Error CS0236](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5724t6za.aspx)

```
// CS0236.cs
public class MyClass
{
   public int i = 5;
   public int j = i;  // CS0236
   public int k;      // initialize in constructor

   MyClass()
   {
      k = i;
   }

   public static void Main()
   {
   }
}
```